# ShinyApp errors: selectInput, data-subsetting

Tags: r, data.table, shiny, subset, shinydashboard

I am creating shiny app. My goal is to visualize some data slices depending on the input.I am quite happy with the result. 
However, my app has a few bugs while the app is loading. Before ploting the graph and visualizing inputs it shows some errors on screen (you can lauch the app and see the problem).

I believe, the first problem is with data filtering. I can't figure out how to deal with it and what is the problem. May I need to use other method or maybe other package? (see the `output$Brand`).

`Error in grep(pattern, levels(vector)) : invalid 'pattern' argument`

The second error comes when I am creating `selectInput`. I'd like to visualize all the brands of the specific category in one plot and to have an option to filter data by brand. However, my method is not working well. Any suggestions? (see the `output$Brand`).

`Error in if (input$Brand == "All") { : argument is of length zero`

Also, I enclose the code, which you can generate.

May you have any more suggestions how to simplify the code?

Thanks for the help!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(scales)
library(ggthemes)



# Header -----------------------------------------------------------

header <- dashboardHeader(title="Dashboard")

# Sidebar --------------------------------------------------------------

sm <- sidebarMenu(
  menuItem(
    text="Graph1",
    tabName="Graph1",
    icon=icon("home")
    )
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(sm)

# Body --------------------------------------------------

body <- dashboardBody(

# Layout  --------------------------------------------  

tabItems(
 tabItem(
  tabName="Graph1",

  fluidPage(
         fluidRow(

      box(
        title = "Inputs", status = "warning", width = 2, solidHeader = TRUE,

        uiOutput("Year"),
        uiOutput("Category"),
        uiOutput("Brand"),
        sliderInput("Finalas.Range", "Months:",
                    min = 1, max = 12, value = c(1,12)) 

         ),

      box(
        title = "Season", width = 10, status = "info", solidHeader = TRUE,

        plotOutput("Graph1")

   )  
  )
)
)
)
)

# Setup Shiny app UI components -------------------------------------------

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, skin="black")

# Setup Shiny app back-end components -------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output) {

# Generate data --------------------------------------

  set.seed(1992)
  n=99
  Year <- sample(2013:2015, n, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)
  Month <- sample(1:12, n, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)
  Category <- sample(c("Car", "Bus", "Bike"), n, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)
  Brand <- sample("Brand", n, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)
  Brand <- paste0(Brand, sample(1:14, n, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL))
  USD <- abs(rnorm(n))*100

  df <- data.frame(Year, Month, Category, Brand, USD)



  # Inputs --------------------------------------
  output$Year <- renderUI({
  selectInput("Year", 
            "Year:", 
            c(unique(as.character(df$Year))), selected = "2015")
  })


  output$Category <- renderUI({
    selectInput("Category", "Choose category:", 
            choices = c("Car","Bus", "Bike" ))
  })


  output$Brand <- renderUI({
    df2 <- (data.table(df))[like(df$Category,input$Category)]
    selectInput("Brand", 
            "Brand:", 
            c("All", unique(as.character(df2$Brand)))) 
  })


  # Plot --------------------------------

  output$Graph1 <- renderPlot({

df <- data.table(df)

      if (input$Brand == "All") {

        df <- df[like(df$Year, input$Year)]   
        df <- df[like(df$Category,input$Category)] 

        ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(Month,levels=1:12), y=USD, fill=Brand))+
          geom_bar(stat='identity')+
          scale_x_discrete('Month', breaks=factor(1:12), drop=FALSE)+
          scale_fill_gdocs(guide = guide_legend(title = "Brand"))

      } else {


        df <- df[like(df$Year, input$Year)]   
        df <- df[like(df$Category,input$Category)] 
        df <- df[which(df$Brand == input$Brand),]

        validate(
          need(sum(df$USD)>0, paste(input$Brand, "was inactive in Year:",input$Year))
          )

        ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(Month,levels=1:12), y=USD, fill=Brand))+
          geom_bar(stat='identity')+
          scale_x_discrete('Month', breaks=factor(1:12), drop=FALSE) 
      }

  })

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

}

# Render Shiny app --------------------------------------------------------

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should eliminate these errors: for #1 the function `like` in `datatable` gives out the error so I changed it to `%in%` instead. and for #2 you have a `null` as a default so take care of that with an `if` statement

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(scales)
library(ggthemes)


# Header -----------------------------------------------------------

header <- dashboardHeader(title="Dashboard")

# Sidebar --------------------------------------------------------------

sm <- sidebarMenu(
  menuItem(
    text="Graph1",
    tabName="Graph1",
    icon=icon("home")
  )
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(sm)

# Body --------------------------------------------------

body <- dashboardBody(

  # Layout  --------------------------------------------  

  tabItems(
    tabItem(
      tabName="Graph1",

      fluidPage(
        fluidRow(

          box(
            title = "Inputs", status = "warning", width = 2, solidHeader = TRUE,

            uiOutput("Year"),
            uiOutput("Category"),
            uiOutput("Brand"),
            sliderInput("Finalas.Range", "Months:",
                        min = 1, max = 12, value = c(1,12)) 

          ),

          box(
            title = "Season", width = 10, status = "info", solidHeader = TRUE,

            plotOutput("Graph1")

          )  
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

# Setup Shiny app UI components -------------------------------------------

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, skin="black")

# Setup Shiny app back-end components -------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output) {

  # Generate data --------------------------------------

  set.seed(1992)
  n=99
  Year <- sample(2013:2015, n, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)
  Month <- sample(1:12, n, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)
  Category <- sample(c("Car", "Bus", "Bike"), n, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)
  Brand <- sample("Brand", n, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)
  Brand <- paste0(Brand, sample(1:14, n, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL))
  USD <- abs(rnorm(n))*100

  df <- data.frame(Year, Month, Category, Brand, USD)



  # Inputs --------------------------------------
  output$Year <- renderUI({
    selectInput("Year", 
                "Year:", 
                c(unique(as.character(df$Year))), selected = "2015")
  })


  output$Category <- renderUI({
    selectInput("Category", "Choose category:", 
                choices = c("Car","Bus", "Bike" ))
  })


  output$Brand <- renderUI({


    # first error
    #df2 <- (data.table(df))[like(df$Category,input$Category)]

    df2 <- df[df$Category %in% input$Category,]


    selectInput("Brand", 
                "Brand:", 
                c("All", unique(as.character(df2$Brand)))) 
  })


  # Plot --------------------------------

  output$Graph1 <- renderPlot({

    df <- data.table(df)

    if(is.null(input$Brand) || is.na(input$Brand)){return()}

    else if (input$Brand == "All") {

      df <- df[like(df$Year, input$Year)]   
      df <- df[like(df$Category,input$Category)] 

      ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(Month,levels=1:12), y=USD, fill=Brand))+
        geom_bar(stat='identity')+
        scale_x_discrete('Month', breaks=factor(1:12), drop=FALSE)+
        scale_fill_gdocs(guide = guide_legend(title = "Brand"))

    } else {


      df <- df[like(df$Year, input$Year)]   
      df <- df[like(df$Category,input$Category)] 
      df <- df[which(df$Brand == input$Brand),]

      validate(
        need(sum(df$USD)>0, paste(input$Brand, "was inactive in Year:",input$Year))
      )

      ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(Month,levels=1:12), y=USD, fill=Brand))+
        geom_bar(stat='identity')+
        scale_x_discrete('Month', breaks=factor(1:12), drop=FALSE) 
    }

  })

  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

}

# Render Shiny app --------------------------------------------------------

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is one more question about subseting.
Fuction `like` allows the partial matching. Is there another way to do partial match?

Comment: Generally `%in%` works quite well and is widely applicable. Alternatively you can look into `match` or `subset`. There are also a number of versions out there within packages such as `ddplyr`, `data.table`, `sqldf` that would do the subsetting quote well, I would recommend using `data.table` package as in some cases it outperforms others and offers bread functionality in data table manipulation. Don't spend too much time on sub-setting unless you are doing very computationally intensive tasks then its better to work with lists and matrices oppose to data frames

Comment: I have found one more problem in here:

`df2 <- df[df$Category %in% input$Category,]
df2 <- (data.table(df))[like(df$Category,input$Category)]`

The first line works good.
However, what I like to do is to filter partial matches. For example, when I select `Midfielder` filter must include `Midfielder / Striker`.
The `like` function does the job, but I get an error while the app is loading. Any suggestions?